# Trouble Making Soundboard in Django Html Template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, audio

I'm setting up a django website, and I've made a html template for the page I want the soundboard to be in. In the template, I wrote some code for a button, and it runs fine, but when I click the button, the sound doesn't play.

I've tried making a new directory in my templates directory and loading it from there, but to no avail. The mp3 works perfectly as it should when played normally (the windows groove app thing).

This is the html template. In my template directory, there's a file named 'bruh.mp3'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
<head>
    <title>The Bruh Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="bruhsound" src="bruh.mp3"></audio>

    <button onclick="document.getElementById('bruhsound').play()">BRUH</button>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want it to do is for the button to play the sound file on a click. Preferably, for every button click, the sound file restarts. In other words, if you spam click the button, each click would interrupt the current sound playing, so it essentially can be spammed.

Comment: The src needs to be a URL. Where is the `bruh.mp3` file? How is it being served to the browser?

Comment: the mp3 file is in the same directory as the template, so it's 'C:\Users\Oliver\Projects\Bruh_Button\bruh\templates\bruh\bruh.mp3'

Comment: Well that's not how it works at all. It needs to be a static file, in the static directory, and referenced via the `{% static %}` tag.

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly. Thanks a bunch!